# is delimiting data in a database field ok

Tags: database, database-design

Is delimiting data in a database field something that would be ok to do?

Something like

```
create table column_names (
  id int identity (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  column_name varchar(5000)
);
```

and then storing data in it as follows

```
INSERT INTO column_names (column_name) VALUES ('stocknum|name|price');
```

Comment: no ... use enum, pair-value ... etc other than delimiter text

Comment: No, that's bad.  Use a many-to-many construct.

Comment: I wouldn't. Use something structured instead e.g. `create table column_names( id int identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, column_name varchar(50) not null, column_order int not null);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. this is bad:

- in order to create new queries you have to track down how things are stored.
- queries that join on price or name or stocknum are going to be nasty
- the database can't assign data types to the data or validate it
- you can't create constraints on any of this data now

Basically you're subverting the RDBMS' scheme for handling things and making up your own, so you're limiting how much the RDBMS tools can help you and you've made the system harder to understand for new people.

The only possible advantage of this kind of system that I can think of is that it can serve as a workaround to avoid dealing with a totally impossible DBA who vetoes all schema changes regardless of merit. Which can happen, unfortunately.

Of course there's an exception to everything. I'm currently on a project with audit-logging requirements that are pretty stringent. the logging is done to a database, we're using delimited fields for storing the fields because the application is never going to interact with this data, it gets written once and left alone.

Comment: Agree the OP's idea is pretty much the worst way you can store data.

Comment: @HLGEM: i've seen worse, in a varchar(2000) column using XML instead of pipe-delimiters. >_<

Answer (score 4):

Almost certainly not.

1. It violates principles of normalization.  The data stored in a particular row of a particular column should be atomic-- you shouldn't be able to parse the data into smaller component parts.
2. It makes it substantially more difficult to get acceptable performance.  Every piece of code that queries this table will need to know how to parse the data which is generally going to mean that more data needs to be read off disk and potentially sent over the network to the client.  Every query that has to parse this data is going to have to be more complex which tends to cause grief for the query optimizer.  Concatenated data cannot generally be indexed effectively for searches-- you'd have to do something like a full-text index with custom delimiters rather than a nice standard index on a character string.  And if you ever have to update one of the delimited values (i.e. because a product name changes), those updates are going to have to scan every row in the table, parse the data, decide whether to actually update the row, and then update a ton of rows.
3. It makes the application much more brittle.  What happens when someone decides to include a | character in the name attribute, for example?  Even if you specify an optional enclosure in the spec (i.e. | is allowed if the entire token is enclosed in double quotes), what fraction of the bits of code that actually parse this column are going to implement and test that correctly?

Comment: *Atomic* doesn't quite mean "you shouldn't be able to parse the data into smaller component parts". It means that, if a value *has* component parts, the dbms either a) ignores that fact, as it does when you `SELECT CURRENT_DATE`, or b) provides functions to manipulate the parts, as `SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE)`. The important thing about *atomic* in the dbms sense is that *the user* doesn't have to write any code to manipulate the parts. +1 anyway.